# FragmentManager FrameLayout

Tags: java, android

В общем я хочу сделать некое подобие TabLayout with ViewPager но без использования первого и второго. В роли TabLayout у меня будут выступать кнопки а в роли ViewPager - FrameLayout. Думаю не надо объяснять теорию как это должно работать. Для тех кто скажет мне что это глупо - мне нужно именно так. А проблема вот в чем, я вроде как и все сделал, нажимаю на кнопку, на старый фрагмент наклеивается другой и т д, но когда я нажимаю на тот фрагмент, на который я уже нажимал, и он находится уже в стеке - выдается ошибка. Мне нужно чтобы при  нажатии кнопки выводился определенный фрагмент в FrameLayout, но вот стек фрагментов мне тут препятствует, что делать

Comment: Для начала вам нужно сделать следующее - оформить вопрос согласно [требованиям данного ресурса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), то есть создать минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Я вычислил ваш IP, но файрвол не дал мне залезть в папку с вашим проектом и я не могу тем самым видеть ваш код и сказать что именно там не так. Придётся вам выложить минимальный код сюда, указать строку падения и логи ошибки приветси

Comment: Вам нужно перед созданием фрагмента проверять его наличие во FragmentManager если он там есть - доставать его и ставить во FrameLayout. Именно так делает и ViewPager

Comment: а каким методом ставить его во FarmeLayout если он уже есть